# Limiting text size using graphics.drawText in ListField in order to put suspension points?

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I'm trying to think how must i calculate the width of the text or if exist an easy way to do that in blackberry 4.5 in order to put the ... in the text. I'm using this to draw text:

```
graphics.drawText(auxString, row_height, y+row_height/2, DrawStyle.VCENTER, width-width/list_width_factor-(row_height+20));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already tryed using DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS ? :

```
graphics.drawText(auxString, row_height, y+row_height/2, DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS, width-width/list_width_factor-(row_height+20));
```